# commutator subgroup and normal soupgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group we denote with [G,G] the commutator subgroup, let N be normal in G and [G,G].

I want to use the statement:$$[G,G]/N\cong [G/N,G/N] $$

my idea for the proof was to define a surjective homomorphism 
$$ f:[G,G]\rightarrow [G/N,G/N]$$
$$ x\rightarrow[x]$$
and then proof: $\ker(f)\cong N $, but this seems to be obvious and then I would be finished, is this true?

Comment: Is it really clear that $\ker f =N$? What if some element wasn't in the commutator but is up to an $N$-coset? I'm not sure I'm convinced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.

If $f\colon G\to G'$ is a surjective group homomorphism, then
$$
f([G,G])=[G',G']
$$
Indeed, if $x,y\in G'$, then $x=f(a)$ and $y=f(b)$, so
$$
[x,y]=[f(a),f(b)]=f([a,b])
$$
Thus $[G',G']\subseteq f([G,G])$. The converse inclusion is easy as well and holds also when $f$ is not surjective.

Therefore the canonical map $\pi\colon G\to G/N$ induces a surjective homomorphism $\pi'\colon [G,G]\to[G/N,G/N]$. What's the kernel of $\pi'$? We have
$$
\ker\pi'=[G,G]\cap\ker\pi=[G,G]\cap N=N
$$
By the homomorphism theorem,
$$
[G,G]/N\cong[G/N,G/N]
$$